# How to compile a C extension as part of a ruby gem with mkmf on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to create a gem that wraps `libpuzzle`, but cannot figure out this `flat_namespace` issue:

```
--- personal/sayzame ‹master* M⁇› » gem build sayzame.gemspec && gem install sayzame-0.0.1.gem
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: sayzame
  Version: 0.0.1
  File: sayzame-0.0.1.gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sayzame-0.0.1
1 gem installed
--- personal/sayzame ‹master* M⁇› » pry -rsayzame -Ilib                                       
[1] pry(main)> Sayzame.compare_images :a, :b
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _puzzle_init_dvec
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libpuzzle.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _puzzle_init_dvec
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libpuzzle.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    56394 trace trap  pry -rsayzame -Ilib
```

My full source code here: https://github.com/neezer/sayzame

I'm fairly sure the problem is in my `ext/puzzle/extconf.rb` file, in that I am not linking the library correctly. I have already posted on [`ffi/ffi`'s issue tracker](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/246) about it and followed up on those two leads with no success.

I would really appreciate any and all help here; been banging my head against the wall for quite sometime on this.

Possibly related:
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/picky-ruby/8kuG8FkATgU/89JLc6U7SrcJ

Comment: I believe I had this issue a long ago. IIRC, upgrading xcode command line tools fixed it.

Comment: I just updated the command line tools in Xcode, and have the same issue still. :/

Comment: Do you get this same error on Ubuntu GCC, not Mac LLVM?

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson - Just fired up a fresh Vagrant box with the default lucid32 image, compiled ruby 1.9.3p374 from source, and installed `libgd2-xpm-dev` (requirement for libpuzzle)... compiled and installed the gem, then ran as above, an no errors--seemed to work just fine. Pretty sure this is specific to Mac OS X.

Comment: I just wrote a similar gem like yours yesterday using Ruby C API: https://github.com/tonytonyjan/libpuzzle_ruby
But I found your link is dead. I wonder if you are still woking on it?